# Neural network predicts one class only

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I was implementing a neural network with the MNIST dataset, and I am having issues in terms of classifying 10 classes. I am pretty sure the implementation of feed-forward and back propagation is correct, and I have used Xavier initialization to initialize the weights. When running mini-batch gradient descent, with only $1$ epoch, the lowest loss I have obtained with standard deviation is $0.3288$ as shown in the graph below:
[image]

Complete graph of $J(\theta)$:

[image]

Note that I'm using a zero-indexed implementation, which means $\frac{\partial{J(\theta)}}{\partial{\Theta^{(l)}}} = a^{(l)}\delta^{(l - 1)}$, and $a^{(l)} = \sigma((\Theta^{(l - 1)})^Ta^{(l)})$

The model has $2$ hidden layers with $10$ nodes each (excluding the bias term). Activation functions for layers $a^{(l)}, \text{ where } l > 0$  Cross-Entropy loss is used for every node in every layer.

As my training data is normalized, normalized test data is used to test the accuracy of the model. Despite a low cost, my model only predicts one class.

You can find the source code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VQOYlj3TLKj8deDZ_ZD_JY-VVv2asaHq?usp=sharing).

To summarize, I have two questions:

1. What does negative cost indicate?
2. Why is my model only predicting one class?

Comment: I am not able to find 1. OHE for Labels. 2. Softmax for Output layer 3. Neurons count for the output layer. Please answer these points

Comment: @10xAI [1] OHE labels can be found in nn.batch_y [2] I don't have a softmax output layer. I simply used np.argmax to determine the highest probability [3] Neurons for each layer can be found in nn.layers[i].nodes, where i is the index of the layer